# Installing GPU enabled tensorflow in Windows 10 with PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I want to install TensorFlow on my windows 10 device with GeForce Mx150 GPU. I am familiar with PyTorch and have installed it easily with my preferred IDE- Pycharm. But when it comes to TensorFlow, there are many factors, and all the tutorials I have seen require Visual Studio.
I don't want to use VStudio as I am not familiar with it.

I tried one installation method where it generates `dll` error and I also tried to check installation with
`tf.test.is_gpu_available()` which gives `FALSE`.

But with PyTorch environment with `torch.cuda` and also `torch.device_name` it shows GPU availability and even GPU name.

And with `nvidia-smi` it says cuda version `11.5`.

I don't have the exact error messages as I don't have the device, right now but I will update the post in time.

Now I have the following:

1. miniconda installed
2. Python 3.6
3. Git bash(not necessarily required as I can run cmp/shell in windows)
4. Pycharm 2019 edition.

How do I install GPU-enabled TensorFlow?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the instructions listed in the [tensorflow installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native) that follows the GPU set-up. The VStudio requirement is only to download a C++ library requirement for tensorflow and not for actually using the IDE.